# Isotope imagesLoaded Not Working With Filters

Tags: javascript, image, overlapping, jquery-isotope

I want to use isotope.js with Filters and FitRow Layout. But when I try this code, all images are overlapping.

```
var $container=$(".portfolio-content");
$container.isotope({itemSelector:".portfolio-items",layoutMode:"fitRows"});
$("#filters").on("click","a",function(){var a=$(this).attr("data-filter");
$container.isotope({filter:a})});
$(".button-group").each(function(b,a){var c=$(a);c.on("click","a",function(){c.find(".is-checked").removeClass("is-checked");
$(this).addClass("is-checked")})});
```

When I try to use ImagesLoaded plugin, filters are broke and not working. Here is code with imageloaded:

```
var $container = $('.portfolio-content');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container.isotope({itemSelector :".portfolio-items",layoutMode : 'fitRows'});
});
$("#filters").on("click","a",function(){var a=$(this).attr("data-filter");
$container.isotope({filter:a})});
$(".button-group").each(function(b,a){var c=$(a);c.on("click","a",function(){c.find(".is-checked").removeClass("is-checked");
$(this).addClass("is-checked")})});
```

Anybody have an idea? I just want to use isotope.js with filters working properly.